# java protobuf run-time formal example not working

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am trying to run the official example for protobuf in java source from [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/examples),
followed the README.md 
protoc generate the javasource code fine but I can not run the code by:

1- java AddPerson data

or

2- java -cp protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar AddPerson

1- Error for java AddPerson data is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
"com/google/protobuf/MessageOrBuilder
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at AddPerson.main(AddPerson.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more"
```

2- Error for:   java -cp target/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar AddPerson

```
Error: Could not find or load main class AddPerson


[enter image description here][2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including the current directory in the classpath:
`java -cp .:target/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar AddPerson`

The `.:` is to append classpath. For windows, it is `;` instead of `:`.[1]

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: Thank you @Hari Menon, I did and error is now changed to number 1 above.
(Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)